# How can i make this border around 0 shown in the image where background is dynamic and I need the cutting part of bubble to be transparent

Tags: html, css

```css
.square {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #000;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 0 6px;
        position: relative;
}
 .square:before {
            border-left: 10px solid transparent;
            border-right: 0 solid transparent;
            border-top: 10px solid #000;
            bottom: -10px;
            content: '';
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            transition: all 0.25s linear 0s;
            right: 0;
            width: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="square">
0
</div>
```

[image]

In the shown image i want to achieve the border around the zero using css only.
I tried this but i want hollow arrow so help me out.
I tried speech bubble but in my case background is dynamic and I need the the cutting part of bubble to be transparent

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: Please share your HTML/CSS. Only then will people be able to help you out.

Comment: i m trying using css triangle but none of that help me.

Comment: Search google for "speech bubble CSS"

Comment: Thanks mplungjan

Comment: I tried speech bubble but in my case background is dynamic and I need the the cutting part of bubble to be transparent

Comment: Why not just use an SVG as the outline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```css
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #339FFF;
    padding: 15px;
}

.child {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.child:before{
   content: '';
   border-top: 5px solid #339FFF;
   border-left: 5px solid #FFF;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -5px;
   right: 0px;
   z-index: 1;
}

.child:after {
   content: '';
   border-top: 10px solid #fff;
   border-left: 10px solid #339FFF;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -13px;
   right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="mask">
      <div class="child">0</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the code. It is fixed width. Is it possible to do it with percentage to make it flexible width? I want the width to change based on number of characters.